# Use tipsy with Angular 2 and D3.js jQuery tipsy

Tags: jquery, angular, d3.js, tipsy

The following works  with D3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/ilyabo/1373263

```
$('svg circle').tipsy({
    gravity: 'w',
    html: true,
    title: function() {
        var d = this.__data__,
            c = colors(d.i);
        return 'Hi there! My color is <span style="color:' + c + '">' + c +
            '</span>';
    }
});
```

Not sure how to do this with angular 2 D3.js and include  jQuery tipsy for popup